# Convert RGB to color scale defined by any two colors

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, colors

I am working in Matlab. I can successfully read in an image:

```
img = imread('image.jpg');
```

Although `img` matrix contains RGB color values, the actual image is predominately composed of 2 colors, therefore I want to do away with the RGB values stored in the `img` matrix, and instead I want to define the color in terms of a scale defined by the 2 colors.

For example, if I were to use Grayscale, I would convert RGB values to a scale defined by black and white (and all shades between). For my purposes, I want to create my own "grayscale" (but with two different colors). So, if my picture contains mostly black and yellow, I want to convert RGB to a scale that goes from black to yellow, and store these values. However, I am not sure how to figure out the conversions. Any ideas?

Comment: I think [`rgb2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html) as in the suggested duplicate will get you what you want. If it doesn't, let me know and I'll remove the duplicate vote.

Comment: I think I can work with that ^. Thank you